# Too many arguments to function error even though I have a function with the right number of arguments

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

unsigned int idiv_rec(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
 if (b == 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 unsigned int l = 0, h = a;
 return idiv_rec(a, b, l, h);
}

unsigned int idiv_rec(  unsigned a,  unsigned b, unsigned &l, unsigned &h) {
 unsigned int m = (l + h) / 2;
 bool greater = m * b > a;
 h = greater ? m : h;
 l = greater ? l : m;

 if (h - l > 1)
  return idiv_rec(a, b, l, h);
 else
  return l;
}
```

it says

> too many arguments to function 'unsigned int idiv_rec(unsigned int, unsigned int)'

Do I have to include something?

Comment: you declared the function to take 2 arguments and are passing 4..

Comment: When you are calling the function idiv_rec() you are passing four arguments, but the parameters for the function are only two integers

Comment: I guess it because the type of a and b in your function overload is not `unsigned int` try to do this `unsigned int idiv_rec(  unsigned int a,  unsigned int b, unsigned &l, unsigned &h)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned int idiv_rec(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
 if (b == 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 unsigned int l = 0, h = a;
 return idiv_rec(a, b, l, h);   //<---here
}
```

At the point of call, the compiler is yet to *see* your `4` argument version. You should forward declare the 4 argument version before you call it either at the outer namespace(in this case global namespace) or **inside** the function (within the function scope, yes C++ allows it)!:

```
// (1)
unsigned int idiv_rec(  unsigned a,  unsigned b, unsigned &l, unsigned &h);

unsigned int idiv_rec(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
  //or (2)
  unsigned int idiv_rec(  unsigned a,  unsigned b, unsigned &l, unsigned &h);

 if (b == 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 unsigned int l = 0, h = a;
 return idiv_rec(a, b, l, h);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i know my mistake now :)

Comment: @kirekhar you can also save yourself a forward declaration and define the  4 parameter version before the 2 parameter version. That way there is one less thing you have to change if, for example, the 4 parameter function becomes a 5 parameter function.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is when you reach

```
return idiv_rec(a, b, l, h);
```

The compiler has not yet seen

```
unsigned int idiv_rec(  unsigned a,  unsigned b, unsigned &l, unsigned &h)
```

This means it does not know there is a 4 argument version of the function.  That is why you get an error even though the function exists.

You will need to forward declare it like

```
unsigned int idiv_rec(  unsigned a,  unsigned b, unsigned &l, unsigned &h);
```

Before

```
unsigned int idiv_rec(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @kirekhar No problem.  Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Its called as function prototype or function interface is a declaration of a function that specifies the function's name and type signature (arity, data types of parameters, and return type), but omits the function body.